# Windows Mobile compse window

Tags: windows-mobile

I am trying to send a e-mail from windows mobile 6.5.I am able to do it with creating my own form.Is there any way to go directly to email-compose task by code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Mobile POOM API to compose an eMail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912570.aspx